# Assigning variables?

Tags: for-loop, each, office-2010

I have looked for awhile to find the answer, I see some similar codes and try to adjust my code to work. Basically, I need all textboxes on my `userform` to turn red with white font based on the text received from another work sheet in one of the textboxes. I know I am close, but I don't understand the placement of wording!

```
Sub ChangeClr() 
Dim tbMyTextBox As TextBox 
Dim ufMyUserForm As UserForm 
For Each tbMyTextBox In ufMyUserForm 
    If tbAction1 = "Tank In Spec" Then 
        tbMyTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen 
        tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack 
    Else 
        tbTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen 
        tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack 
    End If 
Next tbMyTextBox 
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you do some 'coding for the web' here, but you forgot to include what kind of language you are writing in, and also the piece of code you need help with/improvement suggestions of. In short, you need to improve your question/problem statement to get any help.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are working with? Don't worry about how - focus on the input you have and output you want and provide if possible the simplest  example of code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sub ChangeClr() Dim tbMyTextBox As TextBox Dim ufMyUserForm As UserForm For Each tbMyTextBox In ufMyUserForm If tbAction1 = "Tank In Spec" Then tbMyTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack Else tbTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack End If Next tbMyTextBox End Sub

Comment: hmm I am having trouble with the comment box, I cant seem t paste in my code and add text as to answer your questions.  I am using Office 2010 and using VB6.  I am trying to write a sub routine to call on userforms that change the colors of all the text boxes based on a value receieve in one of those texh boxes. I hope that I explained it correctly

Comment: How to you click to the next line?  When I hit the Enter key it sends out a post...I just want to go to the next line..

Comment: @RalphSevernsIII To add new information/code, please click edit below your question and add it to the question itself. The comments are not meant for additional information or code.

Comment: I tried that but my code just compressed it self into a mess.  So sorry, I just need to learn more about this site and how to do thing...:)

Comment: Put the code in the question and indent each line of it with (at least) four spaces. (I'd do it myself, but I don't know where you want the line breaks.)

Comment: I think your code is in Excel-VBA instead of VB6, And what is `tbAction1` ;).

Comment: I think you are looking for accessing to a textbox in a sheet of your excel file, If yes try `Sheets(0)` object that 0 is index of your sheet or use `ActiveSheet` object for accessing to current sheet ;).

Comment: I have a new question I am going to try and see if I can do this correctly... thanks!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know you are using VBScript in Excel, this code will loop thru and change all text boxes (including the action one) based on the wording in the action text box.  You can tweak to your exact specifications.

```
Dim varControl As Control


For Each varControl In ufMyUserForm.Controls

 If TypeOf varControl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
         If tbAction1 = "Tank In Spec" Then
            varControl.BackColor = vbRed
            varControl.ForeColor = vbWhite
         Else
            varControl.BackColor = vbGreen
            varControl.ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: that would be most helpful.  I am trying  to paste my code in the comment window but I guess i am doing it wrong,

Comment: Sub ChangeClr()

Dim tbMyTextBox As TextBox
Dim ufMyUserForm As UserForm

          For Each tbMyTextBox In ufMyUserForm
     
               If tbAction1 = "Tank In Spec" Then
                    tbMyTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen
                    tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack
               
               Else
                    tbTextBox.BackColor = vbGreen
                    tbMyTextBox.ForeColor = vbBlack
                    
               End If
               
          Next tbMyTextBox
     
End Sub

Comment: Ugh so Sorry, everytime I try to paste my sub routine it does see the my rows and spaces and jsut crams it all together

Comment: That works perfectly!!!! You have no idea how good it is to see it work.  I hope to learn more and hope my questions for help are not too basic for this site.:)